# Android attr to xml drawables

Tags: android, android-theme

**TL;DR** I looking for an implementation of `public static Drawable getDrawableFromAttribute(Context context, String attrName)`.

---

I'm searching for a way, to load dynamic drawables, which are defined in my style with custom attributes. That's my configuration

**attr.xml**

```
<resources>
   <attr name="custom_image" type="reference">
</resources>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
   <style name="demo">
      <item name="custom_image">@drawable/fancy_picture</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

The **fancy_picture** is a named **/res/drawables/fancy_pictures.xml**.

Now, I want someone to enter the string "custom" and "image" and the `ImageView` should show the fancy_picture in it.

What is the best way to do this? If I use a XML-Layout file, I could write

```
<ImageView
    ...
    android:src="?custom_image"
    ...
    />
```

I didn't use **declare-styleable** in my style xml and I would like to ignore them completely, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public static Drawable getAttrDrawable(Context context, @AttrRes int attrRes) {
    Drawable drawable = null;
    TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
    if (context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(attrRes, value, true)) {
        String[] data = String.valueOf(value.string).split("/");
        int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(data[2].substring(0, data[2].length() - 4), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        if (resId != 0) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                drawable = context.getDrawable(resId);
            } else {
                drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(resId);
            }
        }
    }
    return drawable;
}

public static Drawable getAttrDrawable(Context context, String attr) {
    int attrRes = context.getResources().getIdentifier(attr, "attr", context.getPackageName());
    if (attrRes != 0) {
        return getAttrDrawable(context, attrRes);
    }
    return null;
}
```

and it worked well for attr -> xml and attr -> png.